# Api load testing with certain scenarios

Tags: load-testing, api

Hei. I've done some api testing with java using restassured framework, but this doesn't seem to have a good solution for load testing. I would need a recommendation for a tool that could help me with it.

The problem is that the load testing will be done between "users". I have 2 sets of users and I want to create tests where they communicate with each other etc.

Example: 
2 sets of users. Each set has 100 users.

Case 1:

- User1 from set 1 sends a message to User2 from set 2.
- User2 from set 2 responds to User1 from set 1.
- User2 will do smth etc.

Basically I need to write load tests where I test the interaction between multiple users. I want to see if the servers can handle alot of interactions going on at the same time.

Restassured sadly doesn't support it and I need and alternative solution which allows me to handle these cases.

Comment: Try soapUI, it may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any load testing tool which supports HTTP protocol and parameterization will suit, here is a shortlist:

- [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) is kind of web service functional testing standard. It has some limited [load testing capabilities](https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/concept.html) as well
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) is kind of load testing standard in free and open source software world, it is multiprotocol modular solution which [supports web service testing as well](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter). Using JMeter you will be able to create more load and get extended reporting.

Answer (score 0):

You can record Case 1: scenario using blazemeter chrome extension that generates .jmx file and imports it into the Jmeter and set your threads to 100 users.